# What's wrong with this CreateWindowEx function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, api, visual-c++

Okay, so first a little overview of what I am tryna do..
I am trying to create 3 child window in a main parent window, and use `EnumChildWindow` and `EnumChildProc` to enumerate them, I want to create 3 child windows of same height as of parent but 1/3rd width, and align them one after the other..

So, I captured the `WM_CREATE` msg to create those child window, and `WM_SIZE` to move and align them using `MoveWindow`, everything is fine except for the fact that no child window is created. When I debugged it, I found that (in the Autos Window in Visual Studio 2008, while debugging) my CreateWindowEx statement is not getting executed (the autos window said "**Expression cannot be evaluated**."

Here's the statement:

```
CreateWindowEx(0, (LPCWSTR)("childClass"), (LPCWSTR)NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU) (int) (ID_FIRSTCHILD + 1), hInst, NULL);
```

of course I was using it in a for loop to create 3 windows, but that's the other thing...
So, can anyone please help/guide/advice me what is going on in here? Or what am I doing wrong?

ps: I am reading this ebook from where I got this code and all, so please don't ask me to adopt another approach or something, say put the Child creation code somewhere else or so... because I am not making any program, but just following a book's example... :)

Comment: Have you copied `(LPCWSTR)("childClass")` from that book as well? Does that really work?

Comment: Yeah, it was in the book like this, but I also tried to change it to the class same as that of parent, i.e. `szWindowClass` that visual studio creates by default for the main window, but it didn't do any good either..

Comment: I'm not really sure, but that smells odd to me. Try replacing it with `L"childClass"`...

Comment: can it be that the default class `szWindowClass` created by VS is not suitable for those child windows as it has the `.lpfnWndProc` set to `WndProc` while the Proc that is going to handle those child window is `EnumChildProc`, if that so, do I need to create a new class for child window and register it?

Comment: Well I did tried `_T("ChildClass")`...

Comment: Nope! nothing with `L"ChildClass"` too...

Comment: You're mixing up your procs! WndProc is called by the OS whenever something happens. EnumChildProc is called by EnumChildWindow each time it discovers a child window of your main window.

Comment: Create a child window larger than 0 x 0 pixels.

Comment: You say your call to `CreateWindowEx()` is not getting executed... have you tried stepping through your code to see if it really is getting skipped? If it does get called, what does `GetLastError()` say immediately after the call to `CreateWindowEx()`?

Comment: @Razort4x: You seriously need to get a different book. The code `(LPCWSTR)("childClass")` already makes the book highly suspect. Refer to [this link](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) or [this link](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/window/) instead.

Comment: @zenzelezz
Yeah the call to CreateWindowEx returned NULL, and when I checked GetLastError() (@err) I got 1407, which I found out indicates that the window class is not registered. I was just placing this "ChildClass" text as just dummy text, this doesn't represent any actual class, so do I have to register one, if so do I register WndClass or WndClassEx?

Comment: @Razort4x If you use CreateWindowEx, you use WNDCLASSEX - if you use CreateWindow, you use WNDCLASS. However, if you're just testing some code and don't care about the actual type of window that is created, you could use a system-provided class like "BUTTON".

Comment: You do not need to match CreateWindowEx with WNDCLASSEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic powers suggest you need to pass in the WS_VISIBLE style to the CreateWindow call above for your child windows - so you can seem them. :)

My development experience suggests the following:

What is the return value of CreateWindowEx?  Did you assign the return value to a variable. And if so, did you set a breakpoint on that line in the debugger?  And if the return value from CreateWindow is NULL, then what is GetLastError (which you can evaluate in the debugger as "@err").

After your main window pops up (with the children invisible), did you run Spy++ to see if the child windows exist?  What is their state?

Otherwise, did you validate that the WM_CREATE callback of the WndProc of your child window class is getting called?

Comment: Yes, I checked it in debugger the call returned NULL, then I checked for @err it returned 1407, which, on googling, I found indicates that the window class specified in `CreateWindowEx` is not registered.
Also, if I register this class, since I would be registering this for child window(s) what should I specify in WndClassEx::lpfnWndProc method? Cause in the parent class its value is `WndProc`. So should it be same for this case or different?
So do I have to register this "ChildClass"? Earlier I just placed this text string in the code but it doesn't specify anything actually.

Comment: All instances of the same window class will have the same wndproc callback function. You likely need two window classes.  One for the parent and one for child windows (each window class has a seperate wndproc function callback). Register both window classes when the app starts.  Use the lpParam argument to CreateWindow to pass initialization data to each window if they are to behave differently.